# expandable optional parameter to enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, expansion, labels, paralist

The MWE below, by using `paralist` package, is supposed to allow `\begin{enumerate}[...]` where `...` is flexible in "some way" (inherits from `enumerate`s above).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{paralist,xargs}

\newcommand\mwe[2]{[{\ref{#1}.}.#2]}

\begin{document}

\newenvironmentx{enumwe}[2][2=1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}\mwe{#1}{#2}%
  %\expandafter\begin\expandafter{\expandafter enumerate\expandafter}\mwe{#1}{#2}%
  \ignorespaces%
}{\end{enumerate}%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{enumerate}[{A}1]

\item \label{one} {\bfseries~Appendix One}

  \begin{enumwe}{one}
    \item text
  \end{enumwe}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, the commented line seems a wrong attempt, while the MWE typesets wrong.

The expanded result expected would be the following.

```
\begin{enumerate}[{A}1]
\item \label{one} {\bfseries~Appendix One}
  \begin{enumerate}[{A1.}1.]
    \item text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

P.S.: I actually need to expand a macro in the optional parameter to `enumerate` environment, like `\begin{enumerate}[\mwe{...}1.]`, but it's not working (the `??` occurs everywhere) and this MWE is my approach, but I got stuck  with the weird error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 21 ended by \end{enumerate}.
```

Comment: You should use the package `enumitem` instead which is more flexible and allows what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: sorry, all the rest of the class core code involved is based on `paralist`, for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\expandafter` only steps over a single token not brace groups, so the simplest thing is to put everything you want to step over into a single token:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{paralist,xargs}

\newcommand\mwe[2]{[{\ref{#1}.}.#2]}

\begin{document}

\newenvironmentx{enumwe}[2][2=1]{%
  \def\temp{\begin{enumerate}}%
  \expandafter\temp\mwe{#1}{#2}%
  \ignorespaces%
}{\end{enumerate}%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{enumerate}[{A}1]

\item \label{one} {\bfseries~Appendix One}

  \begin{enumwe}{one}
    \item text
  \end{enumwe}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```